# ¿Cómo hallar el valor mínimo y máximo en una matriz en Python?

Tags: python, matrices

[Python] Tengo la siguiente matriz y deseo hallar el valor más pequeño y el valor más grande sin usar Numpy ni ninguna otra biblioteca. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
A = [292, 410, 754]
    [67, 792, 989]
    [573, 537, 703]
```

Comment: Esa no es una lista válida en Python. Por favor, edita la pregunta y corrige el código.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saber los valores máximos y mínimos de cada lista que contiene tu matriz, que por cierto esta mal para la sintaxis de Python, podemos usar un  ciclo `for`

**Matriz correcta**

```py
A = [[292, 410, 754],
    [67, 792, 989],
    [573, 537, 703]]
```

Vamos a iterar en cada lista que contiene la matriz `A` para posteriormente sacar sus valores máximos y mínimos y los guardamos en una lista en forma de tupla

```py
valores = []
for l in A:
    maximo = max(l)
    minimo = min(l)
    valores.append((maximo,minimo))

print(valores)
#salida-> [(754, 292), (989, 67), (703, 537)]
```

Pero si lo que quieres es sacar el máximo y mínimo de toda la matriz, pues ahí cambia el procedimiento, pues para esto usaremos la función `map()`

```py
maximos = list(map(lambda x: max(x), A))
minimos = list(map(lambda x: min(x), A))

print(f"maximos: {maximos}")
print(f"minimos: {minimos}")
```

**resultado**

```
maximos: [754, 989, 703]
minimos: [292, 67, 537]
```

Comment: Funciones con un sólo argumento, como `max` y `min`, es redundante encerrarlas en una expresión lambda. Directamente puedes ponerlas como `map(max, A)`. O mejor como `[max(row) for row in A]` lo que te evita convertir a lista después.

Answer (score 0):

Usando *expresiones generadores*

```
a = [[292, 410, 754],
    [67, 792, 989],
    [573, 537, 703]]

maximo = max(max(fila) for fila in a)
minimo = min(min(fila) for fila in a)

print(minimo, maximo)
```

Una expresión generadora es como comprensión de listas que no devuelve una lista, sino un elemento a la vez. Evita tener que crear una lista innecesariamente.

Así

```
max(fila) for fila in a
```

Calcula el máximo de cada fila, con lo que generamos una lista de máximos. Aplicando nuevamente `max`, tenemos el máximo de todos los elementos.

produce

```
67 989
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de resolver este tipo de problemas.
Uno de ellos es aplanar la matriz por medio de comprensión de listas y después usar las funciones max y min sobre ella:

```
A = [[292, 410, 754],
    [67, 792, 989],
    [573, 537, 703]]


plana=[x for y in A for x in y]
print(f"el valor máximo es: {max(plana)} y el mínimo es: {min(plana)}")
```

Devuelve:

```
el valor máximo es: 989 y el mínimo es: 67
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que el objetivo es hacerlo sin usar ninguna función predefinida, entonces se podría:

```
A =[ [292, 410, 754],
    [67, 792, 989],
    [573, 537, 703]]
```

esa sería la matríz correctamente declarada, que no es otra cosa que una lista de listas

```
max=A[0][0]
min=A[0][0]
```

creamos valores máximos y mínimos con el primer elemento de la matriz

```
for x in A:
    for z in x:
```

con el primer ciclo obtenemos cada lista de la matriz
y con el segundo cada elemento de la lista

```
    if z > max:
         max = z
    elif z < min:
         min = z
```

comparamos el elemento con los valores y si sumplen las condiciones asignamos el nuevo valor

```
print(max,min)
```

por último los mostramos

Answer (score 0):

La forma más simple es usando una *expresión generadora* que pase por todos los elementos de la matriz mediante un doble bucle:

```py
maximo = max(x for row in A for x in row)
minimo = min(x for row in A for x in row)
```

También se podría haber creado una lista "plana", como se sugiere en otra respuesta, pero la ventaja de una expresión generadora es que no necesita crear ninguna lista intermedia, lo que puede suponer un ahorro de memoria en caso de que la matriz fuera bastante grande.

La pega es que estamos recorriendo la matriz dos veces, una para sacar el máximo y otra para el mínimo. Se podría hacer algo para que sólo recorra la matriz una vez, aplicando `functools.reduce`:

```py
from functools import reduce

def max_min(t, x):
    a,b = t
    return (max(a, x), min(b, x))

inicializador = (A[0][0], A[0][0])
res = reduce(max_min, (x for row in A for x in row), inicializador)
maximo, minimo = res
```

Si nunca has visto cómo funciona `reduce` puede costar entender este código. Cuando la matriz es pequeña, no se gana mucho con respecto a recorrerla dos veces como hemos hecho antes.